# Chrome menu options not revealed through Ubuntu Unity HUD

Tags: 13.10, google-chrome, hud

I am running Chrome Version 33.0.1750.70 beta and I can't get any menu commands to appear in the Unity HUD.

Is there any way to force this or is it up to Google developers to add this into Chrome source?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hud/+bug/1197213, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306667 . It is fixed in chrome 35 as the UI stack moves to aura, which will be released to stable hopefully within a month.